# python importing order logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have encountered the next code, and I cant understand the difference between the 2 version:

Verison 1:

```py
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM, Convolution1D, Flatten, Dropout
```

Version 2:

```py
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Convolution1D, Flatten, Dropout
```

Why there is a unique line for the Dense import from keras.layers?

Answer (score 0):

the only reason is just bad formatting,
 there is no difference between

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM, Convolution1D, Flatten, Dropout
```

and

```
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Convolution1D, Flatten, Dropout
```